# Spark alternative to scipy stats norm pdf function

Tags: python, scala, scipy, apache-spark-mllib

How do I calculate the probability density function in Scala spark? (perhaps through mlib) 
In python we have `norm.pdf` function in which is present in `scipy.stats`